# Why is the Witcher's hair white?

Tags: the-witcher

In The Witcher, the eponymous Witcher's hair is white. This is mentioned frequently in the series, even inspiring a nickname: *The White Wolf*. This seems to be a distinguishing feature of Geralt in particular.

How so? What's the story behind his white hair?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's a consequence of the mutations he underwent during the additional experiments performed upon him as part of his training/conversion into a Witcher:

> I underwent the usual mutation there, through the Trial of Grasses, and then hormones, herbs, viral infections. And then through them all again. And again, to the bitter end. Apparently, I took the changes unusually well; I was only ill briefly. I was considered to be an exceptionally resilient brat…and was chosen for more complicated experiments as a result. They were worse. Much worse. But, as you see, I survived. The only one to live out of all those chosen for further trials. **My hair's been white ever since. Total loss of pigmentation. A side effect, as they say.** A trifle.
>
> - [*The Last Wish*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PzhQydl-QD8C&pg=PT116&lpg=PT116&dq=%22I+underwent+the+usual+mutation+there,+through+the+Trial+of+Grasses,+and+then+hormones,+herbs,+viral+infections.%22) (The Voice of Reason 4)

This loss of pigmentation is presumably the reason why his skin is also pale.

The reason he is the only Witcher like this is that no other child has survived these additional experiments.

Comment: I think a bit later on there is speculation that his resilience is caused by the fact that his mother was an enchantress - the rare children of mages are almost always "special" in some way, but usually not in a good one.

Comment: I'd like to challenge your last sentence - there's no indication it's true (absence of evidence isn't evidence of absence), and it's also possible the extra trials simply hadn't been applied to anyone else.

Comment: @Gallifreyan what are you talking about? The quote explicitly says Geralt was "The only one to live out of all those chosen for further trials."

Comment: Welp, I shall be reading the posts thrice before digesting them from now on. Sorry for that :D